# Get the second element under mouse that isn't a parent of the first element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making a card drag and drop board in `HTML5` similar to Trello.

I am working on attaching the lists to list slots/containers.

When I am `onMouseDown` on a list, the list will move with the mouse. I need to be able to check what list container is below the mouse pointer when I `onMouseUp`. This will allow me to then attach the list to that container.

currently I am having difficulty in trying to get the container element under the mouse. As the list is directly under the mouse at the time I am trying to see what's under the mouse.

I cant get the parent element of the list I'm dragging as the parent will always return the original list parent, As I am dragging the list with changing the Top and Left attributes which doesn't change the parent element.

So essentially I need to see what's under the mouse, excluding the list that I am dragging. When I'm dragging over list slot 1 I need to get that element, and when dragging over list slot 2 I need to get that element.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";





export default function Main() {
  const [mousedown, setmousedown] = useState(0);
  const [etop, setetop] = useState(0)
  const [epostiontype, setepostiontype] = useState("relative")
  const [eleft, seteleft] = useState(0)

  ///////////////////
  let offsetX, offsetY;
  const move = e => {
    const el = e.target;
    el.style.left = `${e.pageX - offsetX}px`;
    el.style.top = `${e.pageY - offsetY}px`;
  };

  const add = e => {
    const el = e.target;
    offsetX = e.clientX - el.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    offsetY = e.clientY - el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    el.addEventListener('mousemove', move);
  };

  const remove = e => {
    const el = e.target;
    el.removeEventListener('mousemove', move);
  };
  ///////////////////////
  const [list_states, setlist_states] = useState(
    [
      {
        name: "This is list 1",
        id: 1,
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }
    ]
  );
  var getParents = function (elem) {

    // Set up a parent array
    var parents = [];

    // Push each parent element to the array
    for (; elem && elem !== document; elem = elem.parentNode) {
      parents.push(elem);
    }
    // Return our parent array
    return parents;

  };

  function mouse_moving_in_container(props) {
     // gets mouse position
     var x = props.pageX, y = props.pageY

     var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

     console.log(element)

    // checks if mouse is down over a list. The mousedown var is the element id of the lsit that is being clicked. If no list is being clicked then the var is 0
    if (mousedown != 0) {
      var difference = props.pageY - document.getElementById("List_1").offsetTop
      var mouse_top = props.pageY - 10
      var mouse_left = props.pageX - 10
      setepostiontype("absolute")
      setetop(mouse_top)
      seteleft(mouse_left)


     
      // gets the element under the mouse
      var elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y)
      //returns array of all parents for the element above
      var element_parents = getParents(elementMouseIsOver)

      element_parents.forEach(element => {
      //  console.log(element.id)
     
        if (element.id.includes("Container")){
         // console.log("TThere is a <List>  container under mouse. ID: ")

        }
        else {
          //console.log("There is NO <List>  container under mouse.")
        }
        
      });
    }





  }



  return (
    <div className={"testing"}>
      <Container >
        <Slot>
          <List></List>
        </Slot>

        <Slot>

        </Slot>
      </Container>


    </div>


  );

  function change_mouse_status(event) {
    // console.log("change status",event)
    setmousedown(event)

  }




  function List() {
    return (
      <div
      
       id="List_1" className="width" style={{
        height: "100px",
        width: "180px",
        background: "red",


        position: `${epostiontype}`,

        // "relative",
        top: `${etop}`,
        left: `${eleft}`

      }}

        onMouseUp={() => change_mouse_status(0)}
        onMouseDown={() => change_mouse_status(1)}

      >
        this is a list
      </div>
    );
  }

  function Slot(props) {
    return (
      <div id="slot_1" style={{ display: "inline-flex", padding: "10px", margin: "10px", backgroundColor: "#e8e8ff", height: "200px", width: "200px" }}>
        {props.children}

      </div>
    );
  }

  function Container(props) {
    return (
      <div id="Container_1" onMouseMove={mouse_moving_in_container}
      name='testname'
        style={{
          display: "inline-flex",
          backgroundColor: "#94e49d38",
          height: "400px",
          width: "100vw-10px"
        }}
      >


        {props.children}

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

That is what I have so far.

Any assistant would be appreciated.

Comment: I managed to get the element under the list by setting the list attribute pointerEvents to none. 

However then I cant detect onmouseup to stop the dragging. 

Is there a different way to handle detecting the onmouseup and onmousedown events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by setting the slots `pointerevents` to none when its being dragged. And set back to default when its not being dragged.

I also changed the `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` `event` handler to the `body` of the page to still be able to detect the `event`.

````
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Main() {
  const [mousedown, setmousedown] = useState("0");
  const [etop, setetop] = useState(0)
  const [epostiontype, setepostiontype] = useState("relative")
  const [eleft, seteleft] = useState(0)
  const [slot_pointer_events, setslot_pointer_events] = useState("")


  const [list_states, setlist_states] = useState(
    [
      {
        name: "This is list 1",
        id: 1,
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }
    ]
  );
  var getParents = function (elem) {

    // Set up a parent array
    var parents = [];

    // Push each parent element to the array
    for (; elem && elem !== document; elem = elem.parentNode) {
      parents.push(elem);
    }
    // Return our parent array
    return parents;

  };
  document.body.onmousemove = function (props) {
    var x = props.pageX, y = props.pageY

    // gets mouse position

    var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

    //console.log(element)

    // checks if mouse is down over a list. The mousedown var is the element id of the lsit that is being clicked. If no list is being clicked then the var is 0
    if (mousedown != 0) {
      setslot_pointer_events("none")
      var difference = y - document.getElementById("List_1").offsetTop
      var mouse_top = y - 10
      var mouse_left = x - 10
      setepostiontype("absolute")
      setetop(mouse_top)
      seteleft(mouse_left)

      // gets the element under the mouse
      var elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y)
      //returns array of all parents for the element above
      var element_parents = getParents(elementMouseIsOver)

      console.log("this: ", elementMouseIsOver)


      element_parents.forEach(element => {
        //  console.log(element.id)

        if (element.id.includes("Slot")) {
          //   console.log("TThere is a <Slot>  container under mouse. ID: ")

        }
        else {
          //   console.log("There is NO <Slot>  container under mouse.")
        }

      });
    }

    else {

      setslot_pointer_events("")

    }
  }
  var mouseDown = 0;
  document.body.onmousedown = function (props) {
    var x = props.pageX, y = props.pageY
    var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    if (element.id.includes("List")) {

      setmousedown(element.id)
    }
    else {
      setmousedown("0")
    }
  }
  document.body.onmouseup = function () {
    setmousedown("0")
  }

  return (
    <div className={"testing"}>
      <Container >
        <Slot
          slot_id="Slot_1"
        >
          <List></List>
        </Slot>

        <Slot
          slot_id="Slot_2">

        </Slot>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
  function List() {
    return (
      <div

        id="List_1" className="width" style={{
          height: "100px",
          width: "180px",
          background: "red",

          pointerEvents:
            `${slot_pointer_events}`,
          position: `${epostiontype}`,

          // "relative",
          top: `${etop}`,
          left: `${eleft}`

        }}

        onMouseUp={() => change_mouse_status(0)}
        onMouseDown={() => change_mouse_status(1)}

      >
        this is a list
      </div>
    );
  }

  function Slot(props) {
    return (
      <div id={props.slot_id} style={{



        display: "inline-flex", padding: "10px", margin: "10px", backgroundColor: "#e8e8ff", height: "200px", width: "200px"
      }}>
        {props.children}
this is slot (lsit container)
      </div>
    );
  }

  function Container(props) {
    return (
      <div id="Container_1"
        name='testname'
        style={{
          display: "inline-flex",
          backgroundColor: "#94e49d38",
          height: "400px",
          width: "100vw-10px"
        }}
      >


        {props.children}

      </div>
    );
  }
}```
````